# If the earth is negatively charged why is lightning striking it?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, charge, lightning

So, as far as I know, the Earth is negatively charged, and there are such things as lightning strikes which travel from clouds to the Earth- that would mean the clouds in a thunderstorm are positively charged.

If that is the case and if the Earth is negatively charged then the particles that travel from clouds to the Earth, ionizing the air and causing a lightning strike shouldn't be electrons but protons.

Yet, I feel this isn't correct.

Why, if the Earth is negatively charged, do electrons travel to it from the heavens?

Comment: Who's to say it doesn't? How can you tell whether the clouds strike the ground or whether the ground strikes the clouds?

Comment: @user253751 uuuuuuuuuuuuuuhm... science? Scientists? All the instruments we have? Knowledge? Common sense? Need I go on?

Comment: [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Upward_streamers)... You are plain misinformed.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, if you say so. Because that link clearly states "[...] upward streamer, **can** develop [...]" and the very two animations below the section you've linked to show lightnings striking from the clouds downwards. So... either your own link is also misinformed or I am the very God of conciousness and objective rightism.

Comment: Earth positively charged. Did you read on? There are sooo many Gods...

Comment: @CosmasZachos, apologies, I thought you were responding to my response to user69! If you meant to tell me that I am wrong in thinking that The Earth is negatively charged - you are absolutely correct, now I see it's not that straightforward and was misled in uni. To err is human, to say "Yeah, sorry, I'm dumb. :D " is me.

Comment: Gods come and go...

Answer (score 2):

Lightning comes from A charge imbalance caused by disturbance in the clouds. As a negative charge builds up in the cloud it can move toward the ground but it’s a positive charge from the ground that reaches up going to the cloud. This can also happen from cloud to cloud.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I remember that before lightning strikes the ground a "channel" is formed some microseconds beforehand. I'm guessing those are the protons going up and then the electrons follow the same path down?

Comment: @Tessaract   It is positive ions that form the positive charge from the ground level. Any hydrogen is not sitting around the ground.

Comment: @annav, so I'm guessing the negatively charged earth has positive ions near her surface and it's them that go up to the clouds but why would electrons ever go down then?

Comment: @Tessaract  The earth is neutral, that is why we use it as ground , if there is no charge in the clouds !https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Electrical_field_generation

Answer (score 1):

Lightning occurs as a result of huge potential difference between earths surface and the clouds. The potential difference is so high that  electrons from the cloud manage to break the dielectric(air) and reach ground causing Lightning.